# Canvas App: Sending App Request to Specific FB User ID's

Tags: facebook-graph-api, canvas, apprequests

Am developing a Canvas App and have hit a wall. The application performs some function and arrives at a list of user id's to which application requests must be sent. Following the steps on this page

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

I am led to believe that I can specify the userid's in the "to" field and it will work. Infact, the sample on that page also illustrates this. However, when I try it from my application which is in sandbox mode right now - it trips and says "Too many recipients.".

The code in question is trivial. Some posters have said that your application needs to be white-listed for this to work. I couldnt find any page / function that allowed me to submit my application. Popping up the dialog for each user is not an option! please help!

The code is below

FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
                        message: 'Try out my cool app',
                        to: '123,1244',
                    }, requestCallback);

It works when I use one fbuserid, gives "too many recepients" when give more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibility to send an app request to more than one user is brand new. It was announced only two days ago here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/569/

You have to specifically enable Requests 2.0 in the app settings. It's also possible that it's simply not working yet.

Comment: Yeah. I'm just discovering that. I've enabled Requests 2.0 and have posted on the fb developer announcement as well, perhaps something comes out of it.

Comment: An update: I was using the asynch load for FB.init which was causing an issue with the requests dialog and host of other issues - I think that functionality is buggy. I changed it to NOT use an asynch load and the app behaves now in IE / FF. Hopefully this helps someone. Am still battling issues with the multiple recepients in requests, but still this is some progress.

Comment: You have to user some kind of a queue if you use the async load and have inline Javascript that calls the FB object like FB.Event.Subscribe.